# Android Arbitrarily Nested ListView Type Menu

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, menu

I want to create something like this:

[image: widget demo]

That is, a menu which I can feed an arbitrarily nested tree of strings to which will then lead to an activity who has access to the selected item.

Should I create an activity class `TreeSelectActivity` then pass it a `List<TreeNode>` in a bundle and then recursively create a list of the next activities for each item? One activity per item doesn't seem like the correct way of doing this. Maybe it would be better if they were fragments?

What are the pros and cons of different approaches to do this, and which approach is easiest to implement?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?  I need EXACTLY the same thing.

Comment: @some_developer Yeah, I took the approach suggested by Kevin and used an activity to show the current level taking a tree and creating a new activity for each sublevel

Comment: @Eli: Okay.  Sounds like a plan to me.  Does the back button work as expected when you do it that way? (It travels back up the clicks)

Comment: Yeah back button works fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Wizard Pager](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/wizardpager/) to see if this does what you need.

Otherwise, you could implement it as an activity that takes a tree and has an adapter that shows its current level, and then passes subtrees to new activities via intent extras.

Or you could implement it as a Fragment that does approximately the same thing and stay in the same activity and just do FragmentTransactions.

Comment: Looks like the link has expired. Is this the project you referred to? https://github.com/suarezjulian/WizardPager